# Redis 4.0 vs. 5.0 RDB file format conflict: `Can't handle RDB format version 9`

Tags: heroku, redis, heroku-redis

I am using redis-server version `Redis 4.0.9 (00000000/0) 64 bit`. When trying to restore data form an RDB file saved in Heroku Redis (`Redis Version Compliance 5.0.4`). I got this error:

> Can't handle RDB format version 9

I don't want to delete `dump.rdb`. I want to know which `redis` version can support my RDB file? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis versions 5.0 until 6.2 support RDB format version 9.

Redis 7.0 uses a new version 10 format for RDB files, which is incompatible with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had the same problem on docker.

I changed the volume name for a moment on docker-compose.yml

```
### Redis  
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data_TEST
      ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
      networks:
        - backend
```

And then i have build again the docker redis container

```
sudo docker-compose up --build redis
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

1. Master was running old version "v=3.2.9" (It was  installed long
   back and never upgraded [Don't fix it, if it ain't broken ;)]) and,
2. New slave(on an upgraded system) was "v=4.0.9" (which came as part
   of package manager repo)

Even after configuring the new server as slave, replication was failing with "Can't handle RDB format version 9".

Built and installed 5.0.7[after reading Sid's answer], and its now acting as slave with replication going on as expected.